# How to hide unchecked checkbox based on this script?

Tags: jquery

**HTML**

```
<div>Group 1
    <br>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="testing" value="B" checked="checked">A</label>
    <br />
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="testing" value="I">B</label>
    <br />
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="testing" value="A">C</label>
    <br />
</div>
<div>Group 2
    <br>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="testing2" value="B">A</label>
    <br />
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="testing2" value="I">B</label>
    <br />
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="testing2" value="A">C</label>
    <br />
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("input:checkbox").change(function () {
    var checkname = $(this).attr("name");

    if (this.checked) {

        $("input:checkbox[name='" + checkname + "']").removeAttr("checked").parent().hide();
        this.checked = true;
        $(this).parent().show();
    } else {
        $("input:checkbox[name='" + checkname + "']").parent().show();
    }
});
```

The hide/show script when a checkbox is checked works perfectly but if a checkbox is initialy check on window load, how to make it run the above script so it would hide the others not checked ?

http://jsfiddle.net/warface/uvYzW/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following code to trigger the change event on the already checked checkboxes and cause your code to fire.

```
$("input:checkbox[checked]").trigger("change");
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uvYzW/2/

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to the end:

```
$(function(){
    $('input:checked').parent().siblings('label').hide();
    $('input:checked').parent().show();
});
```